# Keep (to) (the) rule

Tags: american-english

Context: "They struggled to keep (to) (the) rule, not letting some students go out in recess or using corporal punishment."

Is "keep rule" a common set phrase in AmE? I've found the phrase in an autobiography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a mass noun, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rule) gives

> **rule**
> Control of or dominion over an area or people.
> *There is no stipulation of a time limit for US political rule and economic control over the country's resources.*

It isn't a very common way of saying 'keep control'.

"Keep to rule" is like "working to rule", that is, strictly by the book.

"Keep the rule" refers to practising a particular rule.